# Vuetify DateTime Picker and VeeValidate issues

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, vee-validate

Vuetify Stepper, DateTime Picker & VeeValidate Errors

I'm implementing site via Vue using Vuetify and VeeValadite. I have the following issues.

1. Date doesn't seem to be format. I want in this format '10-Oct-2019'. Used the plugin but it doesn't seem to work.
2. Getting the following error while I'm trying to select Director's Date Of Birth and value return as false.

[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected Array, String, got Boolean with value false.

3. Removing Directors and Shareholders. It's removing first one instead of current one. E.g When I click on 'Remove' of 'Jane Doe' element, it's removing 'John Doe' instead of 'Jane Doe'.
4. Regarding the VeeValidate, is there a way to collect the error? Now it's showing The directors[index].Name field is required.

This is codepen

```
`https://codepen.io/hiro-john/pen/xxxwaWZ`
```

Finding the solutions for 2 days and I still couldn't solve it. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

A partial response regarding Financial Year End date picker:

You're using `v-model` on the incorrect piece of data, so it's not showing the correct date format (your computed property).
Changing the `v-model` statement to:

`v-model="computedDateFormattedMomentjs"`

and then changing `computedDateFormattedMomentjs` to:

`computedDateFormattedMomentjs () {
    return moment(this.Financial_Year_End).format("DD-MMM-YYYY");
 }`

allows the date to update correctly and display the format you prefer.